# SQL QUERY needed to get POST category (taxonomy) ? - MUST be SQL statement

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

Working on a tool outside of Wordpress to query the wordpress database by POST_ID and return the Category Name associated.  This is for a real estate website, and the Categories are called "mi_neighborhoods" and are referred to by wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy.

In one of my other queries to get all the Category names I use:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM wp_term_relationships
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
    ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT JOIN wp_terms on wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_terms.term_id
    WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'mi_neighborhoods'  
    GROUP BY wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
```

So I have the POST_ID, I need to return the value of the "mi_neighborhoods" for that post.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Before you say, "you should do this in Wordpress" this is an application running along side wordpres, I cannot use the wordpress structure here.  Thank you

Comment: you want to return all the terms that belong to the custom taxonomy 'mi_neighborhoods' for a post with POST_ID ?

Comment: Yes, I have the ID# of the post.. i want to return all the terms that belong to mi_neighborhoods

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this SQL query for the taxonomy '`mi_neighborhoods`' and let's take `POST_ID = 1304`

```
SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON (tt.term_id = t.term_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id) 
WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('mi_neighborhoods') AND tr.object_id IN (1304) 
ORDER BY t.name ASC;
```

In general you can get it from this function:

```
wp_get_object_terms(1304, 'mi_neighborhoods');
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a query that gives you `id/name/slug` of all the terms belonging to the  '`mi_neighborhoods`' taxonomy:

```
SELECT t.term_id, t.name, t.slug  
FROM wp_terms AS t 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON (t.term_id = tt.term_id) 
WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('mi_neighborhoods') 
ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

and here is the same for all non-empty terms:

```
SELECT t.term_id, t.name, t.slug 
FROM wp_terms AS t 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON (t.term_id = tt.term_id) 
WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('mi_neighborhoods') AND tt.count > 0
ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

Comment: Yes thank you this works, one more thing while I have your attention - Can you give me a SQL Query to retrieve a list of the mi_neighborhoods taxonomy's and their respective IDs ?

Comment: ok great, I updated the answer above.

Comment: ok great, good luck with your project.